# Is possible to create a only-general-view in Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to give access to view aggregate data (General View) to a new user (external employee). I don't want to give full access to all data, I want he can only view some global data like number of sessions, users, bounce, etc. In other words, I don't want he can dig into my data, just share the minimum data he needs for his job.

Is possible to create a view like this? How? Or do I need another mechanism to do it? Or may be it's not possible usign Analytics..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't isolate parts of your standard reports to specific people, but you could try to create custom reports for them which contains only information that you want to share.

More info: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en

Comment: Ok, that option could be a valid answer, but how? Any link or explanation?